# Getting issue while retrieving data from database into html dropdown using ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am retrieving the data from database as options into my dropdown and I am having an add button which will add the dropdowns
here I am getting options from database so there are two options so every dropdown which I add should have two options here the problem is

1. for the first time first dropdown is having two dropdowns and when I add another one and revisit the first dropdown is showing is four options that is the two options are being doubled like that when I add 3rd dropdown it is showing every option 3 times i.e 9 options but I want to show everytime 2 options only
   the code is here
2. I had kept disabled for add fa-fa-icon but it is not working i.e if I select any option only the fa-fa-icon should enable I wrote the code for this but not working

```js
   //Select option function
$(document).on("change", ".drop", function() {

 

  //Enable button on selection
  $('#seedoc').prop('disabled', false)


})


//response
var res = {
  "users": ["<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='755'>amilham</p>",
    "<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='706'>a_sarabi</p>"
  ]
}


function getEmails() {
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    $('.drop').append('<option data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
}

function addOne() {

  $('#container').append("<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'><select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'> <option value='' disabled selected>Select your option</option> </select>");
  getEmails();

}
getEmails();
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class=""></div>
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="addOne();" disabled></i>

<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'>
  <select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>Select your option</option>

  </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary shrBtn" style="float:left;" onclick="send()">Send</button>

</div>
```

Please help me anyone thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the `<option>` tags every time you load new items from database. Simply clean dropdowns first, or replace the ones you already have with new ones:

```
function getEmails() {
  $('.drop').html('');
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    $('.drop').append('<option data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
}
```

OR

```
function getEmails() {
  let options = '';
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    options += '<option data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>';
  });
  $('.drop').html(options);
}
```

Im not sure if icon can be disabled. If you dont want to wrap it with button, simply add condition in the event listener. First, instead of "disabled" set `data-enabled="0"` and removing disabled property and the `"onclick=addOne()"` call:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" data-enabled="0"></i>
```

Than, register action for icon click and add condition in it:

```
$(document).on("change", ".drop", function() {

  $('#seedoc').data().enabled = 1; //set data-enabled to true instead of disabled = false

});

$(document).on("click", "#seedoc", function(e) {

  if ($(this).data().enabled) addOne();

});
```

Comment: @ KarolPawlak thank you for answer see this fiddle the disable and enable functionality not working please help me https://jsfiddle.net/ov671twL/12/

Comment: @ Karol Pawlak could you please help me with this!

Comment: Of course: 1. Remove onclick="addOne()" from your icon. 2.Remove one closing bracket from "if ($(this).data().enabled))" - my bad, i've misspelled it. It should be "if ($(this).data().enabled)" Here is the corrected fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9dLh0cw/

Comment: @ Karol Pawlak but still the icon is not disabling without selecting any option in first dropdown also I am able to click that icon and it is showing the next one 
 and in the corrected fiddle there is no icon please help!

Comment: in the fiddle you shared I dont see the icon @ Karol Pawlak

Comment: Im not sure now what are you trying to acomplish. The icon is disabled. When you select element from FIRST dropdown, icon is accessible and allows to add more dropdowns. Should it be disabled after adding new dropdown again, and be enabled only if the new dropdown has selected option? Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afcmh41d/

Comment: disabled means the color of add button should be gray and after selecting option the icon should change to green color like this @Karol Pawlak

Comment: @ Karol Pawlak thank you very much this is the last one see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9thsp3r1/3/ I am not getting select your option as disabled one in the dropdown I want to get it from jquery only not html is it possible

Comment: @ Karol Pawlak thank you accepted your answer please help me for this last one also if you dont mind

Comment: Sure. In function getEmails, replace this: $('.drop').html(''); with this: $('.drop').html("<option value='0' disabled selected>Select your option</option>");

Comment: @ Karol Pawlak I wrote like this 
   \$('.drop').html('<option value='0' disabled selected>Select your option</option>');                 
getting error as Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

please say why this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218882/discussion-between-swith-and-karol-pawlak).